# Finding the limit of $\sqrt{9x^2+x} -3x$ at infinity

Tags: calculus, limits, radicals, limits-without-lhopital

To find the limit
$$\lim_{x\to\infty} (\sqrt{9x^2+x} -3x)$$

Basically I simplified this down to

$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{9+1/x}+3x}$$

And I am unaware of what to do next. I tried to just sub in infinity and I get an answer of $0$ , since $1 / \infty = 0$. However, on symbolab, when I enter the problem it gives me an answer of $1/6$.

Can anyone please explain to me what I need to do from this point? I haven't learned l'Hopitals rule yet so please don't suggest that. Thanks

Comment: The x that you highlighted in your simplification is not supposed to be there.

Comment: Thanks, I factored it out and now I get 1/6!

Comment: You might have a look at a more general question [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30040/limits-how-to-evaluate-lim-limits-x-rightarrow-infty-sqrtnxna-n-1) and also at other post which are [linked there](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/30040). In particular the two questions which were suggested as duplicates so far seem rather similar to your question: [Finding $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \sqrt{9x^2+x} - 3x$](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/62409) and [Limit of $\sqrt{4x^2 + 3x} - 2x$ as $x \to \infty$](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/832115)

Answer (score 3):

For $x>0$ we have 
$$\sqrt{9x^2+x}-3x=\frac{\big(\sqrt{9x^2+x}-3x\big)\big(\sqrt{9x^2+x}+3x\big)}{\sqrt{9x^2+x}+3x}= \\ =\frac{9x^2+x-9x^2}{\sqrt{9x^2+x}+3x}=\frac{x}{\sqrt{9x^2+x}+3x}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{9+\frac{1}{x}}+3}=$$
Thus:
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\big(\sqrt{9x^2+x}-3x\big)=\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{9+\frac{1}{x}}+3}=\frac{1}{6}$$